# How can I adjust 3-D bar plot grouping space in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to space out the bar groups along the x-axis in MATLAB so that all the plots can be seen. And if there are other ideas on how I can make all the columns visible, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default [`bar3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar3.html) produces bars of normalized width `0.8`:

```
x = rand(5,10); % example data
bar3(x) % default
```

[image]

To improve visibility you can **make the bars thinner** and maybe **change the viewing angle**:

```
bar3(x, 0.4), view(-20, 30) % set spacing and camera angle
```

[image]

Also, consider **using an image instead** of 3D bars, so that the height axis is replaced by a color scale (see [`imagesc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html)):

```
imagesc(x), colorbar % use image with color instead of height
```

[image]